# scss import variables by different condition

Tags: css, sass

I want to import variable from `Card.scss`, but keeps error:

```
Undefined variable: "$card-width".
```

How can I import variable correctly ?

**Card.scss**

```
@mixin small-card {
  $card-width: 100px;
  $card-height: 200px;
}
@mixin big-card {
  $card-width: 300px;
  $card-height: 600px;
}
```

**TypeACard.css**

```
@import '../../Card.scss';
@include small-card;
.card {

  width: $card-width;
  height: $card-height;
}
```

**TypeBCard.css**

```
@import '../../Card.scss';
@include big-card;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `@import '../../Card.scss';`

If it's still not working then the directory is most likely wrong, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your variable's file into top where you have imported all other sass files. Thanks.